# Different remaining flag background colors?

Tags: support, comments, flags, design

**Copy-pasted from** [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286726/different-remaining-flag-background-colors).

When trying to flag something, the *remaining flags* count does not always have the same background color.

It is orange for posts and red for comments. I have the impression SO uses very specific colors to stealthily encourage specific behaviour.

Does coloring imply that comments should be flagged with more caution than posts? Or more rarely perhaps? Some users suggested that it might be a bug.

Here is the remaining flag count from the `flag` window, for questions :

[image: Question flag]

And for comments:

[image: Comment flag]